# Detecting embeds in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord.py bot that will respond to embeds sent by others with words such as "procrastinate" "Procrastination" and "procrastinating". I am trying to use a method where the bot will, hopefully, detect these words in an embed and reply to said embed with 'no u'.

This is my code so far:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
     if text in message.content or any(embed_contains(embed, "procastination", "procasting", 
     "procrastination", "procrasting", "do") for embed in message.embeds):
         await message.channel.send("no u")
```

Is there a more effective way of going about this?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to tweak the sample code a bit for perfect execution, but here's what you could try:

```py
    async def on_message(self, message):
        # First check if the message contains an embed.
        if message.embeds:  # -> Returns a List[Embed]
            # Check to see if XXXX is in the embeds description/title etc.
            if 'XXXX' in message.embeds[0].description:
                ...  # Do what you want here
```

Comment: Thanks, for the 'XXXX' can that refer to a list?

Comment: I have not tried that, you can try that out as it is just an example.